# Is the monoid ring of a Noetherian monoid Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian, monoid

Let $M$ be a monoid. Suppose that $M$ is left Noetherian, i.e. that every increasing chain of left ideals in $M$ stabilizes. Then is the monoid ring $\mathbb{C}[M]$ necessarily a left Noetherian ring? If so, is it still true if $\mathbb{C}$ is replaced by an arbitrary left Noetherian ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would imply that all group algebras over fields are Noetherian. Consider the following.

It is well-known (see
*Connell, I. G.*, [**On the group ring**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1963-067-0), Can. J. Math. 15, 650-685 (1963). [ZBL0121.03502](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0121.03502)) that the group ring $R[G]$ being right Noetherian entails that $G$ has the maximum condition on subgroups (and that $R$ is right Noetherian.) So if you take any group without the maximum condition on subgroups, you have a monoid with only trivial left/right ideals, and $R[G]$ cannot be Noetherian. Of course, this all holds with $R=\mathbb C$.

While I was probing for further research, I ran across this which you may want to look at:

*Rush, David E.*, [**Noetherian properties in monoid rings.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(03)00103-8), J. Pure Appl. Algebra 185, No. 1-3, 259-278 (2003). [ZBL1084.13007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1084.13007).